# How would you find the characteristic polynomial of a nilpotent matrix with complex coefficients?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, nilpotence

I'm trying to find the characteristic polynomial of an nxn nilpotent matrix with complex coefficients. I understand how to do it with standard coefficients but I'm a bit confused as to how to proceed with complex coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

it is $$  x^n $$   while the minimal polynomial is some $x^k$ with $1 \leq k \leq n,$ unless your matrix is the zero matrix

Comment: I just want to confirm, does this still apply with complex coefficients?

Comment: yes........................................................

Comment: This actually applies to matrices over any field.